# failed to update variable n after returning the collection of values in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-gallery

I am facing an annoying problem. before returning the collection of values in ts file I updated my `n` values for expect for `n=0 (for (let i=n)` for display all `postedpics(Image)` for n=1 for display all `postedpics` and so on. but after returning, I notice `n` variable is not updated and for that continuously  displaying only for n=0's all  `postedpics`. here is the code:-

component.ts

```
...
  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.galleryPosts = this.getPosts();
    
  }
...

 n:number=0;

  getPosts(): NgxGalleryImage[] {
    const postUrls = [];
    for (let i = this.n; i < this.member.posts.length ; i++) {
         const post = this.member.posts[i];
        for(let j=0; j < post.postedpics.length;j++)
        {
          postUrls.push({
            small: post.postedpics[j]?.url,
            medium: post.postedpics[j]?.url,
            big: post.postedpics[j]?.url
          })

        }
        this.n++;
        return postUrls;
       
    }
}
```

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let m of member.posts">
  <p>{{m.description}}</p>
  <p  *ngFor="let s of m.postedpics">{{s.url}}</p>
  <ngx-gallery class="mt-4" [options]="galleryOptions" [images]="galleryPosts"
               style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 20px;"></ngx-gallery>
</div>
```

when I run, then I found only for n=0's all `postedpics` but I expect for n=0, n=1, n=2's `postedpics`. I am an absolute beginner. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update it following way to check whether its working fine or not.

```
getPosts(): NgxGalleryImage[] {
    const postUrls = [];
    for (let i = this.n; i < this.member.posts.length; i++) {
            const post = this.member.posts[i];
            for (let j = 0; j < post.postedpics.length; j++) {
                    postUrls.push({
                            small: post.postedpics[j]?.url,
                            medium: post.postedpics[j]?.url,
                            big: post.postedpics[j]?.url
                    })

            }
            this.n++;

    }
    return postUrls;
```

}

if you check your code, you are returning posturls after first iteration only.

Comment: you just change logic. i expect for n=0 display all postedpics then n=1 display all postedpics separately. but your code doesnot mean that. your code says all time display all pics which i don't want.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz link so I can look into it?